# How to find AI specialists interested in additive Manufacturing

Tags: ai-field

We recently founded a company in the area of **additive manufacturing**. Our development focuses on making the process easier and liberate time to the user, which I personally believe in as the ultimate promise of any computerised process, including AI, for the public.

We have gone through the usual channels including regular job offers and personal contacts, visiting universities and meetups. However there appears to be a lack of participation of *real* specialists in most of those gatherings as the ones interested in learning about AI are doing just that, and don't show up somewhere where we can find them, although we believe to have a very interesting task at hand.

It appears to be remarkably hard to find specialists in the field, as AI specialists are either employed by huge multinational companies (instead of startups), have no interest in additive manufacturing (because it implies something else than only code) and the challenge of machines (making machines) or just do not pop up anywhere.

**How would a specialist of AI look for someone else in the specific field of additive manufacturing/motion planning/creative strategy and its employment?** *(Or course in the case they do not already know someone.)*

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's not about Artificial Intelligence, as defined in our on-topic page, but about seeking for people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably compile a list of Universities/Instituitions that specialise in Additive Manufacturing, and target graduating students or researchers looking for a new challenge. This may prove more fruitful than targeting the normal channels. You may have to search worldwide, but of course this adds the issue of work visa etc.
There is no easy way to solve this....

Yo can try posting on the [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) forum too.